# Network programming in C, how to write jpeg data correctly?

Tags: c, network-programming

I'm having a bit of an issue where I can't seem to write error free data of a jpeg file.

```
fd_req = open(&request_URI[1], O_RDONLY);
...
else if( strcmp(f_ext, "jpg") == 0 || strcmp(f_ext, "jpeg") == 0 )
{
  //content_type = "image/jpg"; 
  printf("  [test_05b]::  JPEG \n");
  write(sock, status_ok_jpg, strlen(status_ok_jpg));
  while(read(fd_req, &buf, 1))
  {
    write(sock, &buf, 1);//definitely should be some error checkes
  }
}
```

where status_ok_jpg is just

```
 char* status_ok_jpg =
 "200, OK\n Content-type: image/jpeg\n \n";
```

Since I get a request something like "GET /foo.jpg HTTP/1.1" I just need to parse out "/foo.jpg" and store it in request_URI.  The only thing I could guess is that I am opening a binary file incorrectly.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated.  I've been referring to beej's guide and https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_Basics.html which has been immensely helpful, but still stuck at this part.

Comment: You need to add other headers, mainly the content the content length

Comment: I haven't added in content length, I will try that now.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may need to post more of your code.

**CARDINAL RULE:**  *Check the return codes on all syscalls, especially socket calls*

Can you prove that &request_URI[1] is the file you want.  And, can you prove that the open() of it was sucessful (e.g. fd_req >= 0).

Similarly, can you prove that the socket/whatever call for sock was successful, as well as checking error returns on things like connect, listen, accept, setsockopt, etc.

Further if there are any errors opening the file (e.g. fd_req < 0), your while loop will just go on forever.  Recode as follows:

```
while (1) {
    err = read(fd_req,buf,1);
    if (err <= 0) {
        if (err < 0)
            perror("read");
        break;
    }

    err = write(sock,buf,1);
    if (err <= 0) {
        if (err < 0)
            perror("write");
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that for socket writes, if (err < 0), you may need to look at errno for things like EAGAIN, EINTR, etc. which means to have to retry the write.

Socket connections can be dissolved on a whim, so it is especially important to check error returns on all socket read/writes.

Comment: "Can you prove that &request_URI[1] is the file you want."
as a test case I used
    printf("  [test_01]::  %s \n", &request_method_name);
I get: /foo.jpeg
I just quickly tested if open() was successful by
    if(fd_req<0)
and it seems to open correctly.

sock is also successful since I can send text/html files without a problem.

I have yet to test your code, but will do so now.  Thank you

Comment: @Jack The test for open failure is: _if (fd_req < 0) // fail_.  If the actual string passed to open is indeed "/foo.jpeg", this will fail because it's an absolute full path (e.g. wants foo.jpeg in / directory).  You need it to be relative to containing directory and convert it (e.g. /path_to_my_jpeg_files/foo.jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to examine the return results of `read()` and `write()` and appropriately examine `errno` if necessary.
`write()` and `read(`) can return -1 if there is an error.
However you use `write()` to control the while loop.  If it fails with -1, the expression in the loop is still true.  You should also look at the  returns of your `write()` to ensure they worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
write(sock, status_ok_jpg, strlen(status_ok_jpg));
```

I don't see how the receiver is going to know where that stops. But assuming you have that licked:

```
while(read(fd_req, &buf, 1))
{
    write(sock, &buf, 1);//definitely should be some error checkes
}
```

Incorrect and wasteful:

- You're continuing the loop if there is an error (`read()` returned -1).
- You can't write correct networking code without storing the result of `read()/recv()` into a variable.
- Using system calls to transfer one byte at a time is horrifically inefficient.

Your copy loop should look like this:

```
char buf[8192]; // or more, much more
int count;
while ((count = read(fd_rec, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0)
{
    write(sock, buf, count);
}
if (count < 0) // error
    perror("reading from file");
// else count was zero, meaning end of file, which is normal.
```